# How to get sum of different columns in same row?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have got a table :

```
Id | Col1 | Col2 | Col3

1 | 1.1 | 1.2 | 1.3

2 | 2.1 |2.2 | 2.3
```

How can i get with linq the sum of col1+col3 from id 2 ?

Comment: If it's a single row anyway: `var rec=tbl.Single(r => r.Id==2); double sum=rec.Col1+rec.Col3;`

Comment: @dav_i Unclear?? This question is completely clear, I understand and answered it correctly in seconds. How is that unclear? Moderators here are really becoming awful...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Table.Where(row => row.Id == 2).Sum(row => row.Col1 + row.Col3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 TableData.where(t=>t.Id==2).Sum(t=> t.Col1 + t.Col3);
```